# Relation between $\lim_{a \to 0}\int_a^T u(t)$ and the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^T u(t)$

Tags: integration, continuity, lebesgue-integral

Let $u\colon (0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ be function with $u \geq 0$ everywhere and $u$ is continuous on $[a,T]$ for every $a > 0$.

Suppose that the limit
$$\lim_{a \to 0}\int_a^T u(t) \;dt =U(T)-U(0)$$ exists for function $U$.

I want to know if this is enough to conclude that $\int_0^Tu$, the Lebesgue integral, exists and equals $U(T)-U(0)$. If not, is there some theorem that tells me what I need?

Comment: For functions of one sign, the Riemann integral (proper or improper) coincides with the Lebesgue integral, provided the Riemann integral (again proper or improper) exists. The proper case is a theorem proved in most graduate real analysis texts. For the improper case you can use monotone convergence.

Comment: You can easily use the monotone convergence theorem here! The proper Rieamann- and Lebesgue-integral coincide, also $\chi_{[\frac 1 n, T]} u$ converges to $u$ almost everywhere.